# How to skip validation for array that is empty?

Tags: laravel

I have an incoming post data from js like this

```
[form] => Array (
    [name] => 'a form'
    [type] => 'form'
    ...
    [children] => Array (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => Array(
            [title] => 'first'
            [order] => '1'
            ...
        }
        [3] => Array(
            [title] => 'second'
            [order] => '2'
            ...
        )
        ...
    )
    ...
)
```

and rules like

```
[
    'form.name' => 'required|string',
    'form.type' => 'required|string',
    ...
    'form.children.*.title' => 'requered|string'
    'form.children.*.order' => 'requered|integer'
    ...
]
```

What is the best way to completely exclude/skip the `form.children` arrays that are empty and process the ones with data?

Comment: if they're nullable, they're not required. replace "required" with "nullable"

Comment: @MrEvers unfortunately they are. That is actually why I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[
    'form.name' => 'required|string',
    'form.type' => 'required|string',
    ...
    'form.children.*.title' => 'sometimes|string'
    'form.children.*.order' => 'sometimes|integer'
    ...
]
```

`Sometimes` means, if there is something, follow the next rule(s).

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present

Addition:

For more complex situations, f.ex. you are not interested in an order value if there is no title, makes sense right? Try this:

```
[
    'form.name' => 'required|string',
    'form.type' => 'required|string',
    ...
    'form.children.*.title' => 'sometimes|string'
    'form.children.*.order' => 'exclude_if:form.children.*.title,null|integer'
    ...
]
```

I have never tested/used this on arrays though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to completely remove the empty arrays just by filtering them out of the request with laravel's [prepareForValidation()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) method and [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Worked great for me.

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        "form" => [
            "children" => array_filter($this->form["children"])
        ]
    ]);
}
```

[@DimitriMostrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602434/dimitri-mostrey)'s answer worked as well. His answer is a shorter solution without an additional method. Will accept his answer so anyone facing a similar situation can pick the one that suits the most.